# Check for existence of nested type alias and conditionally set type alias

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I wonder how to conditionally set a type alias, based on the existance of a type alias in input argument like this.

```
struct a { using type = int; }

template <typename T> struct wrapper {
    using inner_t = ???how???; // if T::type exists, use T::type, else T
};

static_assert(std::is_same<wrapper<int>::inner_t, int>, "expected int");
static_assert(std::is_same<wrapper<a>::inner_t, int>, "expected inner type: int");
```

One naive attempt is like `std::conditional<std::is_class<T>, T::type, T>` if the existence of a `type` alias is a prerequisite, but is far from being safe, lacking a check for something like `is_alias_present<T, type>`. Besides that `T::type` is potentially not existing for all types resulting in a compiler error.

Apearently [std::experimental::is_detected](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) looks promising, but unfortunately not an option for now.

Not sure if metaprogramming libraries like `boost::mp11` or `boost::hana` are a good approach to get that done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things, the traits to detect presence, and the lazy evaluation.

In C++20, the traits can be done easily with `requires`

```
template <typename T>
concept has_type = requires { typename T::type; }
```

Then the lazy evaluation:

```
template <typename T> struct wrapper {
    using inner_t = std::conditional_t<has_type<T>, T, std::type_identity<T> >::type;
};
```

Comment: Although all 3 posts work and help me to understand and learn, there is only one that I can mark as accepted. I chose this one because it seems the easiest and cleanest.

Comment: It's important to note that this solution only works because `type_identity` provides a `::type` member, and `T` conditionally provides the `::type` member. If the sub-type you wanted to alias was named anything other than `::type` (anything, whether `T::Type`, `T::value_type`, etc), this solution wouldn't work as-is without a different `type_identity`-like type

Answer (score 4):

With the help of C++20 concepts

```
template<class T>
struct innter {
  using type = T;
};

template<class T>
  requires requires { typename T::type; }
struct innter<T> {
  using type = T::type;
};

template <typename T> 
struct wrapper {
  using innter_t = innter<T>::type; // if T::type exists, use T::type, else T
};
```

In C++17, you can use `void_t` to detect the validity of `T::type`

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class = void>
struct innter {
  using type = T;
};

template<class T>
struct innter<T, std::void_t<typename T::type>> {
  using type = typename T::type;
};

template <typename T> 
struct wrapper {
  using innter_t = typename innter<T>::type; // if T::type exists, use T::type, else T
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GErfedfqz)

Answer (score 3):

One option is to write a type trait like

```
template <typename T, typename = void >
struct type_member
{
    using type = T;
};
 
template <typename T >
struct type_member<T, std::void_t<typename T::type>>
{
    using type = typename T::type;
};

template <typename T >
using type_member_t = type_member<T>;
```

and then you would use it in wrapper like

```
template <typename T>
struct wrapper
{
    using type = type_member_t<T>::type;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename wrapper<int>::type, int>, "expected int");
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<typename wrapper<a>::type, int>, "expected inner type: int");
}
```

This works by leveraging SFINAE and if `typename T::type` is ill-formed in `std::void_t<typename T::type>` then that specialization of `type_member` is discarded and we fall back to the non-type member specialization.